# How to explore "My Computer" by file uri in MSIE?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, uri

Microsoft Internet Explorer can be used to browse files on the host computer.
e.g. typing `file://c:/` in the address bar wil show you the contents of the C: drive.
I would like to know wether a URI exists that will breng me directly to the *"My Computer"* root.

Something similar to executing `explorer.exe /e,/root,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`

Only needs to work in MSIE 7 or higher, not in other browsers.

UNC notation using the computer name is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an URI, "My Computer" is not a folder. You can launch explorer.exe in IE with an ActiveX.

```
new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Run("explorer.exe /e,/root,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}");
```